# Keep the reference in the formula when cells are copied to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have code below that is working perfectly - But only one thing is missing.
In the sheet "Opgørsel" i have a database, where the formulas drag it in and calculate - When i then let the macro run, it can´t find the database - My quetions is so, how can let the formulas find the database in sheet "Opgørsel" when they are copied over? what should i change or modify?

```
Sub Copypastemeddata()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")

    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to
    StartRow = 1    'Destination row on targetSheet
    With ws
          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).Insert shift:=xlDown
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**This is my formula**: `HVIS=IF function` - It wont do it.

```
=HVIS(B7=$A$34;"";HVIS(B7=$A$33;"";HVIS(B7=$A$35;2*3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$36;
3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$37;SUM(C7:F7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$38;(C7+D7)*2*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$39;
C7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$40;I7*C7;HVIS(B7=$A$41;SUM(C7:E7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$42;(C7+D7)*I7))))))))))"
```

Comment: Are the cells you are copying containing formulas and that is the problem when pasting?

Comment: The formulas are copied finely over, but the formulas have some cells in "opgørsel" that it uses, and i want the formulas to contain those reference to those cells -does it make sense?

Comment: This is my formula - HVIS=IF function - It wont do it." =HVIS(B7=$A$34;"";HVIS(B7=$A$33;"";HVIS(B7=$A$35;2*3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$36;3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$37;SUM(C7:F7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$38;(C7+D7)*2*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$39;C7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$40;I7*C7;HVIS(B7=$A$41;SUM(C7:E7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$42;(C7+D7)*I7))))))))))"

Comment: The formulas, i changed my mind - The formulas, so if a mistake is made, then you can just go over and change some numbers.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is there no `Paste`, either on it's own nor as a paramteer for `Copy`?  `Insert` doesn't paste, does it?

Comment: Right now the formulas is copied over, but it cant find the reference to the database in sheet "opgørsel"

Comment: @ashleedawg - It Works fine as it is? I dont know, what you are refering to exactly.

Comment: @MzBarcaaa - code is too hard to read in comments.  I added your formula to your question.  (You can delete the comment now.)  :)

Comment: @ashleedawg OP wants to be able to keep absolute reference in formulas when pasting to a different sheet i.e. keeps pointing to original sheet and range. And the copy then insert should empty the clipboard.

Comment: If you include the sheet name and absolute references in the original formulas then it should work.

Comment: But there are so many refereces - Can i maybe do something to my database, where i can maybe just say ="Sheet.opgørsel.values=5"? When the cell is used, then it has the reference with it and i dont have to go to all the formulas and write the sheet name in all of them but only in the cells where my database are?

Comment: Why not in your source sheet, qualify all the ranges in the formulas with the source sheet reference? That way the sheet reference will also be copied over to the new sheet along with the formulas. e.g. on the sheet opgørsel, if there is a formula say =A2, change it to =opgørsel!A2 so that when the formula cell is copied over to another sheet it will copy the formula as well as the sheet reference. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @sktneer - Exactly. Just tried to put it in front of my formulas, but it dosent Work?

"=Opgørsel! HVIS(B7=$A$34;"";HVIS(B7=$A$33;"";HVIS(B7=$A$35;2*3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$36;
3,14*F7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$37;SUM(C7:F7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$38;(C7+D7)*2*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$39;
C7*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$40;I7*C7;HVIS(B7=$A$41;SUM(C7:E7)*I7;HVIS(B7=$A$42;(C7+D7)*I7))))))))))"

Comment: Thanks Guys, it worked perfectly - Make an answear, so i can accepted.

Comment: @MzBarcaaa You're welcome! I have posted it as an answer as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not in your source sheet, qualify all the ranges in the formulas with the source sheet reference? That way the sheet reference will also be copied over to the new sheet along with the formulas. e.g. on the sheet opgørsel, if there is a formula say `=A2`, change it to `=opgørsel!A2` so that when the formula cell is copied over to another sheet it will copy the formula as well as the sheet reference. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Please remember that you just don't need to prefix your formula with the sheet reference but you should qualify all the ranges used in the formula with the sheet reference.